# How to display post based on which is clicked

Tags: wp-query

I have a sidebar with all my post the page only displays one post at a time. I want to display the post that is clicked from the sidebar.

This is the single post display

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h1 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="the-date"><p><br><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></p></div>
        <div class=""><p><?php the_content(); ?></p></div>
    <?php endwhile ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

This is the side bar displaying post i want to populate the post area

```
<?php
$recent_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'offset' => 1
);
$the_recent = new WP_Query( $recent_args );
if ( $the_recent->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_recent->have_posts() ) : $the_recent->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="more-news">
            <a href=""><?php  the_title();  ?> </a>
        </div>
        <hr>
    <?php endwhile ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sidebar, replace this:

```
<a href=""><?php  the_title();  ?> </a>
```

with this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php  the_title();  ?> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It displays the permalink for the current post, so you need to put the_permalink in your a href tag, example:
`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all,you don't have to run a custom query in your **single.php**.

If the first code you posted above is your **single.php** then wordpress would load that template file when you open a single post.

The problem with your template file is, you're running another query in it, ignoring the global query which wordpress would have run to display the single post.

To resolve this, in your **single.php**, you should have:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
        <h1 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="the-date"><p><br><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></p></div>
        <div class=""><p><?php the_content(); ?></p></div>
    <?php endwhile ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

In your sidebar, your query is fine, but you should also call [**`wp_reset_postdata()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) and pass [**`the_permalink`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) as the href property to a tag.

```
<?php
$recent_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'offset' => 1
);
$the_recent = new WP_Query( $recent_args );
if ( $the_recent->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_recent->have_posts() ) : $the_recent->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="more-news">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php  the_title();  ?> </a>
        </div>
        <hr>
    <?php endwhile ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif ?>
```